# Haskell: get rid of parentheses in liftM2

Tags: haskell

How to remove the parentheses marked with `^`, without introducing new names? (better if it can be splitted into multiple lines)

```
liftM2 (+) (somefunc arg1 (get arg2)) (somefunc arg3 (get arg3))
           ^                        ^ ^                        ^
                                     -
```

Comment: This is one of the reasons why I would like `$` to be left associative: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/ChangeDollarAssociativity. It would allow you to write code like `liftM2 (+) $ exp1 $ exp2`.

Comment: @Sarah I should learn to read more carefully. Thanks.

Comment: @AaditMShah Sometimes I've done things like ``liftM2 (+) `id` exp1 `id` exp2`` (not in that case, though.)

Comment: Don't make `$` left associative, define a different operator.

Comment: Wouldn't it be really easy to define your own left associative `$` (with a different symbol)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can get rid of the last one by using `$`, but the other one cannot obviously be removed without introducing new names. A better solution may be to use the fact that any `Monad m` should also be `Applicative` and `Functor` (and *will* be, come GHC 7.10)

Your example then becomes

```
import Control.Applicative ((<$>), (<*>))

(+) <$> somefunc arg1 (get arg2) <*> somefunc arg3 (get arg3)
```

Comment: And even in the meantime, you can use `return f \`ap\` x \`ap\` y` for `f <$> x <*> y`

Comment: @Cactus Or closer to the metal: `f \`fmap\` x \`ap\` y`.

Comment: @Cactus However, every data type that's an instance of `Monad` is also usually an instance of `Functor`. All the standard data types indeed are.