# Haskell: Get a prefix operator that works without parentheses

Tags: haskell

One big reason prefix operators are nice is that they can avoid the need for parentheses so that `+ - 10 1 2` unambiguously means `(10 - 1) + 2`.  The infix expression becomes ambiguous if parens are dropped, which you can do away with by having certain precedence rules but that's messy, blah, blah, blah.

I'd like to make Haskell use prefix operations but the only way I've seen to do that sort of trades away the gains made by getting rid of parentheses.

```
Prelude> (-) 10 1
```

uses two parens.

It gets even worse when you try to compose functions because

```
Prelude> (+) (-) 10 1 2
```

yields an error, I believe because it's trying to feed the minus operation into the plus operations rather than first evaluating the minus and then feeding--so now you need even more parens!

Is there a way to make Haskell intelligently evaluate prefix notation?  I think if I made functions like

```
Prelude> let p x y = x+y
Prelude> let m x y = x-y
```

I would recover the initial gains on fewer parens but function composition would still be a problem.  If there's a clever way to join this with `$` notation to make it behave at least close to how I want, I'm not seeing it.  If there's a totally different strategy available I'd appreciate hearing it.

I tried reproducing what the accepted answer did here:

[Haskell: get rid of parentheses in liftM2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28524471/haskell-get-rid-of-parentheses-in-liftm2)

but in both a Prelude console and a Haskell script, the import command didn't work.  And besides, this is more advanced Haskell than I'm able to understand, so I was hoping there might be some other simpler solution anyway before I do the heavy lifting to investigate whatever this is doing.

Comment: This can’t really be done and isn’t really necessary. Use more `let`s to make expressions more readable.

Comment: For `(+) (-) 10 1 2` to work, you would need to lookup how many arguments `(-)` and `(+)` expect before being able to parse. Compared to needing to know fixities, this seems a bit more painful. Oh, and this would create ambiguities with unary `-`.

Comment: Why on earth do you want to use prefix notation in a language which was not designed for it? Even if it were somehow possible (e.g. through quasiquotation or TH) it would only lead to terribly unidiomatic code.

Comment: Postfix would be just as nice, ambiguity-wise, and doesn't require remembering which operators are currently awaiting operands. There's a reason RPN calculators are more common and PN calculators.

Comment: @chi I want to use the language as a calculator and I like the ease of prefix notation.

Comment: @Addem I know this is a bit flippant, but may I suggest you get a prefix notation calculator program for your prefix-notation-calculator purposes? I'm pretty sure that an overwhelming majority of programmers would find prefix notation for writing Haskell programs (as opposed to arithmetic expressions in a calculator) to be very difficult to read/write.

Comment: @Ben I could but thought it'd be nice to have it in a programming language, figured I'd ask.  Just asking a question.  The answer could be "no".

Comment: @Addem: I think you could probably make a Haskell quasiquoter that does something roughly similar to the way you proposed in your comment on my answer (if I get some time I might try to whip up a rough demo). But you'd end up having to write `[prefix| + - 10 1 2 |]`. So it's not a terrible question.

Comment: @Ben I get that compliment a lot: "Your question isn't **terrible**."  :)  (joking)

Comment: I'm too lazy to expand it into an answer (someone else feel free) but look at Chris Okasaki's [Flattening Combinators: Surviving without Parentheses](http://www.westpoint.edu/eecs/SiteAssets/SitePages/Faculty%20Publication%20Documents/Okasaki/jfp03flat.pdf).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It gets even worse when you try to compose functions because
>
> ```
> Prelude> (+) (-) 10 1 2
> ```
>
> yields an error, I believe because it's
>   trying to feed the minus operation into the plus operations rather
>   than first evaluating the minus and then feeding--so now you need even
>   more parens!

Here you raise exactly the key issue that's a blocker for getting what you want in Haskell.

The prefix notation you're talking about is unambiguous for basic arithmetic operations (more generally, for any set of functions of statically known arity). But you have to know that `+` and `-` each accept 2 arguments for `+ - 10 1 2` to be unambiguously resolved as `+(-(10, 1), 2)` (where I've explicit argument lists to denote every call).

But ignoring the specific meaning of `+` and `-`, the first function taking the second function as an argument is a perfectly reasonable interpretation! For *Haskell* rather than arithmetic we need to support higher order functions like `map`. You would want `not not x` has to turn into `not(not(x))`, but `map not x` has to turn into `map(not, x)`.

And what if I had `f g x`? How is that supposed to work? Do I need to know what `f` and `g` are bound to so that I know whether it's a case like `not not x` or a case like `map not x`, just to know how to parse the call structure? Even assuming I have all the code available to inspect, how am I supposed to figure out what things are bound to if I can't know what the call structure of any expression is?

You'd end up needing to invent disambiguation syntax like `map (not) x`, wrapping `not` in parentheses to disable it's ability to act like an arity-1 function (much like Haskell's actual syntax lets you wrap operators in parentheses to disable their ability to act like an infix operator). Or use the fact that all Haskell functions are arity-1, but then you have to write `(map not) x` and your arithmetic example has to look like `(+ ((- 10) 1)) 2`. Back to the parentheses!

The truth is that the prefix notation you're proposing **isn't** unambiguous. Haskell's normal function syntax (without operators) **is**; the rule is you *always* interpret a sequence of terms like `foo bar baz qux etc` as `((((foo) bar) baz) qux) etc` (where each of foo, bar, etc can be an identifier or a sub-term in parentheses). You use parentheses not to *disambiguate* that rule, but to group terms to impose a *different* call structure than that hard rule would give you.

Infix operators *do* complicate that rule, and they *are* ambiguous without knowing something about the operators involved (their precedence and associativity, which unlike arity is associated with the **name** not the actual value referred to). Those complications were added to help make the code easier to understand; particularly for the arithmetic conventions most programmers are already familiar with (that `+` is lower precedence than `*`, etc).

If you don't like the additional burden of having to memorise the precedence and associativity of operators (not an unreasonable position), you *are* free to use a notation that is unambiguous without needing precedence rules, but it has to be **Haskell's** prefix notation, not Polish prefix notation. And whatever syntactic convention you're using, in any language, you'll **always** have to use something like parentheses to indicate grouping where the call structure you need is different from what the standard convention would indicate. So:

```
(+) ((-) 10 1) 2
```

Or:

```
plus (minus 10 1) 2
```

if you define non-operator function names.

Comment: True and I had thought of that, but really I think there are good resolutions available.  For one thing, we could assume that all operations--contrasted with functions--are binary and if we want to distinguish the binary and unary - symbol, we could always just use the binary and write - 0 1 to get -1.

Comment: @Adam Yeah, I guess you could make something work. Something like "ordinary terms adjacent to each other are a left-associative chain of applications, an operator term starts a Polish prefix notation chain and continues until the head operator has 2 arguments, in the Polish chain all non-operator terms are operator arguments". So you could say `fmap ($) $ . (f arg) . g (h q (r s)) x foo bar ` for what Haskellers would spell `fmap ($) (f arg . g . h q (r s) $ x) foo bar` (I *think* I got that right). Possible, but definitely not Haskell!